# How to execute a remote command over ssh?

Tags: ssh

I try to connect to the remote server by ssh and execute the command.

But given the situation, I can only execute a single command.

For example

`ssh -i ~/auth/aws.pem ubuntu@server "echo 1"`

It works very well, but I have a problem with the following

case1

`ssh -i ~/auth/aws.pem ubuntu@server "cd /"`

`ssh -i ~/auth/aws.pem ubuntu@server "ls"`

case2

`ssh -i ~/auth/aws.pem ubuntu@server "export a=1"`

`ssh -i ~/auth/aws.pem ubuntu@server "echo $a"`

The session is not maintained.

Of course, you can use "cd /; ls"
but I can only execute one command at a time.

...

Reflecting comments

developed a bash script

```bash
function cmd()
{
    local command_delete="$@"

    if [ -f /tmp/variables.current ]; then
        set -a
        source /tmp/variables.current
        set +a
        cd $PWD
    fi

    if [ ! -f /tmp/variables.before ]; then
        comm -3 <(declare | sort) <(declare -f | sort) > /tmp/variables.before
    fi

    echo $command_delete > /tmp/export_command.sh

    source /tmp/export_command.sh

    comm -3 <(declare | sort) <(declare -f | sort) > /tmp/variables.after

    diff /tmp/variables.before /tmp/variables.after \
                        | sed -ne 's/^> //p' \
                        | sed '/^OLDPWD/ d' \
                        | sed '/^PWD/ d' \
                        | sed '/^_/ d' \
                        | sed '/^PPID/ d' \
                        | sed '/^BASH/ d' \
                        | sed '/^SSH/ d' \
                        | sed '/^SHELLOPTS/ d' \
                        | sed '/^XDG_SESSION_ID/ d' \
                        | sed '/^FUNCNAME/ d' \
                        | sed '/^command_delete/ d' \
                        > /tmp/variables.current

    echo "PWD=$(pwd)" >> /tmp/variables.current
}
```

`ssh -i ~/auth/aws.pem ubuntu@server "cmd cd /"`

`ssh -i ~/auth/aws.pem ubuntu@server "cmd ls"`

What better solution?

Comment: Are you asking how to have an interactive session via SSH? If so, simply leave out the commands and you will be connected.

Comment: I can only execute a single command

Comment: Just use `ssh -i ~/auth/aws.pem ubuntu@server` and you will have an interactive session. Is that what you wanted to achieve?

Comment: no. Execution of the task command, not keyboard typing.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat <<'EOF' | ssh user@server
export a=1
echo "${a}"
EOF
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
user@server's password: 
1
```

In this way you will send all commands to `ssh` as a single file script, so you can put any number of commands. Please note the way to use `EOF` between single quote `'`.

Comment: What you mean as a single command? Is this a single command: `export a=1; echo "${a}"`?

Comment: Why you can only execute a single command? What is restring it?

Comment: Briefly - you can't. A variable exits only in the current session. As a workaround, you can use files to store data between session. Something like "echo 1>/tmp/a" and then "echo `cat /tmp/a`"