# How to have a script trigger in my script after it ssh's into a DC's Time clock server?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, server, scripting

So, I have a script which it's intended purpose is to:

1. Ask for the DC number and Time clock number
2. log in to the Time clock server for the DC stated above
3. After log in, it is intended to run a seperate script inside my script which updates the time clock number also stated above.

My issue is that once I trigger the script, it logs into the server as intended, prompts me for my user ID, and then I have to press "enter" when "xterm" comes up after that. After this, the update script is supposed to run, however, it doesn't, and sits at the command line.

After I exit the server, THEN it runs the update script, but fails, because the update script doesn't exist in the jump box.

My question is, after the script logs in to the server, how can I get it to trigger the script inside the Time clock server, as I am wanting it to? Thanks.

Script is below:

```
#!/bin/bash -x
export LANG="C"

####
####
## This script is intended to speed up the process to setup timeclocks from DC tickets
## Created by Blake Smreker | b0s00dg | bsmreker@walmart.com
####
####

#Asks for DC number

echo "What is the four digit DC number?"

read DC         #User input

#Asks for Timeclock number

echo "What is the two digit Timeclock number?"

read TMC        #User input

#Defines naming convention of tna server

tnaserver="cs-tna.s0${DC}.us.wal-mart.com"

#creating variable to define the update script

tcupd="/u/applic/tna/shell/tc_software_update.sh tmc${TMC}.s0${DC}.us REFURBISHED"

#Logging in to the cs-tna package at the specified DC

/usr/bin/dzdo -u osedc /bin/ssh -qo PreferredAuthentications=publickey root@$tnaserver

echo "Preforming Timeclock update on Timeclock=$TMC, at DC=${DC}"

echo ""

echo "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"

$tcupd #Runs update script

echo "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"

echo ""

sleep 2

echo "If prompted to engage NOC due to Timeclock not being on the network, send the ticket to DC Networking"

echo ""

echo "OR"

echo ""

echo "If the script completed successfully, and the Timeclock was updated, you can now resolve the ticket"
```

Answer (score 1):

You must run the command inside ssh session, not after it:

```
echo "Preforming Timeclock update on Timeclock=$TMC, at DC=${DC}"

echo ""

echo "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"

###### $tcupd #Runs update script
/usr/bin/dzdo -u osedc /bin/ssh -qo PreferredAuthentications=publickey root@$tnaserver /bin/bash -c /u/applic/tna/shell/tc_software_update.sh tmc${TMC}.s0${DC}.us REFURBISHED

echo "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"

echo ""

sleep 2

echo "If prompted to engage NOC due to Timeclock not being on the network, send the ticket to DC Networking"

echo ""

echo "OR"

echo ""

echo "If the script completed successfully, and the Timeclock was updated, you can now resolve the ticket"
```

From [man ssh](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh) you see `ssh    [-46AaCfGgKkMNnqsTtVvXxYy]  ....... destination [command]`. If `[command]` is not given ssh runs remote login command scripts, for example xterm. You read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45684250/ssh-remote-machine-and-execute-command) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45231446/how-to-execute-a-remote-command-over-ssh) or just browse google.
You need to think how and which environment variable you want to pass to the remote machine and remember about properly enclosing the variables, so they get expanded on your or the remote machine.